# Ajax and Show-Hide based on Select Option jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello StackOverflow community,

I tried to implement a dropdown with Show-Hide based on Select Option jQuery it's working.

But when I switch the pages the **javascript won't work anymore**. I have it from here https://codepen.io/atelierbram/pen/gusxF

I altered my version to my needs:

```
<div class="dropbutton dropdown"> 
            <select id="colorselector">
                <option value="leipzig">Leipzig</option>
                <option value="raststatt">Raststatt</option>   
            </select>
        </div>
 <div class="output">
   <div id="leipzig">My Output1</div>
   <div id="raststatt">My Output2</div>
 </div>


 $(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function(){
    $('.colors').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
 });
```

Thank you  and best wishes, raikas.

Comment: What do you mean switch the pages?

Comment: Do all pages have this same code ?

Comment: For example, this page is called dropdown.php but another page is called contact.php when I switch in the navigation between those or any other, the javascript stops working. So all pages have different code.

Comment: You mean you go to contact.php and come back to dropdown.php, it is then where the code doesn't work?

Comment: Or does your contact.php also have the same code?

Comment: contact.php has different code and when I come back to dropdown.php the code won't work anymore. It only works when I directly start from localhost/project/dropdown.php

Comment: If I start from localhost/project/landingpage.php and navigate via the navigation to dropdown.php, it won't work. The page is done with php and this might be why it's not working but all the other explanations on stackoverflow are just to high level for me

Comment: First of all can you add a $ to the first character of your javascript code? Before the ( just add $. So it should be $(function()

Comment: Press "F12" to see the error message in console tab.

Comment: I forgot the $ in the file here, it's working in the code. thanks

Comment: second of all, your HTML code doesn't have any element with class colors, so you need to remove that line.

Comment: Change colors to output in javascript code

Comment: I just deleted it here, to make it "easier" guess it was not the best idea.  So the color class is actually there